# Cannot run the project after setting up react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Basically what I'm asking is if anyone knows how to install react-native-firebase and connect the project to firebase? It should be very easy but it's not working.

I'm using the docs here:
https://rnfirebase.io/#2-android-setup

But I'm installing react-native-firebase instead of react-native-firebase/app because I would like to use react-native-firebase SDK

I'm creating a new project using

```
npx react-native init newProject
```

then install the package:

```
npm install --save react-native-firebase
```

Then I create a new frebase project, add the google-services.json to the app folder, and add the module:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

(Android studio suggests using the latest version)

And:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After that I cannot run the project anymore.
It's stuck:

```
C:\Users\Omer\react-native1\haveri>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1034 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-firebase
react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from C:\Users\Omer\react-native1\haveri\node_modules\react-native\android

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [1m 11s]                                                                                                                                                                             > IDLE                                                                                                                                                                                                             > IDLE                                                                                                                                                                                                             > IDLE                                                                                                                                                                                                             > IDLE                                                                                                                                                                                                             > IDLE                                                                                                                                                                                                             > :app:installDebug
> IDLE
> IDLE
```

If I'm using the version as indicated in the docs:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

I'm getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\Omer\react-native1\haveri\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx' after 10 attempts

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\Omer\react-native1\haveri\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx' after 10 attempts

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

    at makeError (C:\Users\Omer\react-native1\haveri\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\Omer\react-native1\haveri\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Omer\react-native1\haveri\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Omer\react-native1\haveri\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
This is all trying to install the react-native-firebase on a brand new project.
What am I doing wrong? How can I install it successfully?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands. Then start try to run your app again

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried and it's still not working, getting the same errors. I reverted back to just using @react-native-firebase/[whatever module you need]

Answer (score 0):

Try building Gradle from within Android studio. I found that this overcame some build problems sometimes when integrating with react-native-firebase. From Android studio, open your android project by navigating to your /Android folder in your RN project. Let Gradle start syncing and monitor for any errors details.

You may find that there are some JDK path related issues when launching your Android Studio. Try to troubleshoot any errors reported by Android Studio before building.